# RabbitMQ consumer reading from different node in a cluster

Tags: rabbitmq

Suppose we have 3 nodes in a cluster.
node1,node2,node3

In node1 we have a
exchange e1 bounded to a queue q1 with binding key =key1
It is attached to a consumer1.

In node2 we have a
exchange e2 bounded to a queue q2 with binding key =key2
It is attached to a consumer2.

Can consumer2 read messages from q1 in  cluster ? If not how can this be implemented ?

Answer (score 0):

you can read [rabbitMQ route totorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html).Though it's using python,the concept would be the same.In the `Putting it all together` part the consumer 2 can receive info,error and warning from queue 2 while the consumer 1 get error from queue 1.

In your case,c2 can't read message from queue 1 now.To implement,the exchange setting don't need to change.Just bind queue 2 with exchange 1 key 1.